# How to store array data in mysql database laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am getting error `Trying to access array offset on value of type int`

Below is my controller for storing array data into database

```
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->sanitation_point_id); $i++) {
        $sanitation_points[] = [
            'daily_log_id' => $daily_log->id[$i],
            'sanitation_point_id' => $request->sanitation_point_id[$i]
        ];
        SanitationDailylogRelation::create($sanitation_points);
    }
```

Comment: it's better if you show which line and contain of `$daily_log->id` and also `$request->sanitation_point_id[$i]`

Answer (score 0):

array index is started from zero, change your looping initial variable to 0 (`$i = 0;`)

full code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->sanitation_point_id); $i++) {
    $sanitation_points[] = [
        'daily_log_id' => $daily_log->id[$i],
        'sanitation_point_id' => $request->sanitation_point_id[$i]
    ];
    SanitationDailylogRelation::create($sanitation_points);
}
```

or for better handling:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->sanitation_point_id); $i++) {
  if(isset($daily_log->id[$i]) && isset($request->sanitation_point_id[$i]))
  {
    $sanitation_points[] = [
        'daily_log_id' => $daily_log->id[$i],
        'sanitation_point_id' => $request->sanitation_point_id[$i]
    ];
    SanitationDailylogRelation::create($sanitation_points);
  }
}
```

Comment: try option 2 to check using `isset`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($request->sanitation_point_id); $i++) {
        $sanitation_points = [
            'daily_log_id' => $daily_log->id[$i],
            'sanitation_point_id' => $request->sanitation_point_id[$i]
        ];
        SanitationDailylogRelation::create($sanitation_points);
    }
```